# Upload File Directly to Google Cloud Storage from user's webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a web application. 
It is similar to WeTransfer. 
Upload file from browser and share link with receiver.
I want to upload user's file directly to Google Cloud storage, and then share the link of file with someone who can download the file. I have seen some codes of uploading with C# which requires passing of file through our server towards Google Cloud Storage, But I want to directly upload from user's browser (JavaScript) to google cloud storage and then share the link.

Is that possible in any way without exposing credentials to JavaScript?
If yes then HOW?

Comment: Here is a link to the API that one can use to access GCS through REST.  My gut is telling me that you will want to push the data to an intermediary such as Cloud Functions or Cloud Run or COmpute Engine.

Comment: I want to upload file to Google Cloud Storage. Where is the link?

Comment: Apologies ... that was stupid of me to forget the link ... https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of examples on the Internet in most languages including JavaScript. Google search and study how this is done. You are possibly choosing the worst environment for accomplishing your goal (JavaScript in a Browser). Some companies spend months trying to get the browser interface and to upload objects correctly when they need absolutely clean code (no copyright issues) AND need to handle all the problems that the public Internet causes worldwide.

From a design / security view I will give you some tips:

1. You will need to use signed-urls. This prevents leaking credentials. This is a pain to get correct for browser-based uploads. The alternatives are to open the bucket to the public which is VERY DANGEROUS or to use an intermediary such as Google Compute Engine.
2. Providing this service will cost you money. At this time network egress starts at $0.12 per GB and goes up depending on the region. This price will drop in the third/fourth quarter of 2019 to $0.105 per GB.
3. You mentioned sending a link. You will need a form for the user to enter the email address. Then you need to store that email address in a database such as Cloud Datastore.
4. Once the upload completes, you need logic to connect the file upload with the email address stored in step #3. Cloud Storage supports triggers so that a backed service can be notified that the file transfer is complete. You then map the email address to the Cloud Storage object and send an email. Use Cloud Pub/Sub to receive notifications from Cloud Storage and then call either Cloud Functions or Cloud Run to process and fire off the email.

Good luck with this project. Getting a prototype working is not that difficult. Handling all the real world issues, browser incompatibilities, mobile (iOS and Android), etc. will drive you nuts.

Comment: Dear John, I am able to get the signed url(for put method), now when I send file on thAt url from Postman via put method. It doesn't upload nor show any reply, however, file of that name is created in bucket, but empty. What could be that problem?

Comment: When you have a programming question/problem, create a new question with specific details.

Comment: Sure. Apologies. :-)

Comment: @AbdullahTariq - No problem. The goal is to create questions and answers that everyone can benefit from. Fire away we like good questions.

Comment: No problem. I will share screenshots alongwith problem tomorrow.